# PostgreSQL second query based on an array type results from the first query. i.e. chaining queries with arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a graph information that is stored in a database. Each node has an integer id and text label and an adjacency list which is an integer ARRAY of ids. In the first query I'll get a list of nodes, for each node in the result I would like to get the names of all the nodes which are adjacent to it.

```
CREATE TABLE graph (id INTEGER, 
                    name TEXT,
                    adj_list INTEGER[],
                    PRIMARY KEY (id)
                  );
```

Here's the pseudo-code of what I would like to achieve.

```
let node_list = (select * from graph where name like "X%");
foreach node in node_list:
    foreach adj_node in node.adj_list:
        print adj_node.name
```

Can anyone please suggest me on how to write PostgreSQL query to achieve this?

Here is some example data

```
id | name | adj 
---+------+------------
 1 | X1   | {3, 4}
 2 | X2   | {5, 6}
 3 | Y1   | {..}
 4 | Y2   | {..}
 5 | Z1   | {..}
 6 | Z2   | {..}
```

I would like to list all the adjacent nodes of nodes whose name start with `X`. In this example, the results would be {Y1, Y2, Z1, Z2}.

Comment: is adj_list the array?  if so...integer data type?    If you have the opportunity, an array isn't the best way of handling this and there are much better techniques to use, can you change it?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: @Twelfth I'm new to databases, can you please suggest some strategy?

Comment: Arrays like this are 1 to many relations collapsed to a single column. 
 We want to remove that array and replace it with a table and fully define that 1-many relation. Lets call your table here 'node' and create the second as adjacent for example : create table adjacent (node_id int, adj_id int).  so in this new table you have 2 rows for node_ID 1 as 1,3 and 1,4 (node_ID 2 would have two rows as well : 2,5 and 2,6).  Join these tables together when you need to do your look up... select * from node n inner join adjacent a on a.node_id = n.id where name like 'x%' then gives you your 4 results.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a lot easier if you build another table like @twelfth suggests. But if you do want to rock the integer array, I believe you can do something like this:

```
--create the table
create table graph (
  id integer,
  name text,
  adj_list integer[]
);
-- a sample insert
insert into graph (id, name, adj_list)
values
  (1, 'X1', '{3,4}'),
  (2, 'X2', '{5,6}'),
  (3, 'Y1', '{}'),
  (4, 'Y2', '{}'),
  (5, 'Z1', '{}'),
  (6, 'Z2', '{}')
;
-- use a CTE to unnest the array and give you a simple list of integers. 
-- In my opinion this CTE makes the code easier to read
with adjacent_ones as (
  select unnest(adj_list) from graph where name like 'X%'
)
select * from graph where id in (select * from adjacent_ones);
```

This will give you the following

```
--------------------------
|id  |name   |adj_list   |
--------------------------
|3   |Y1     |{}         |
|4   |Y2     |{}         |
|5   |Z1     |{}         |
|6   |Z2     |{}         |
--------------------------
```